# Question related to how to center align via flex attribute

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

[image]

I want to make a page like this picture. To do this, I want to center the part drawn in blue, but my code doesn't work properly. What's wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import {
    Col, Row,
} from 'react-bootstrap';


const content=css`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
`;

const imageContianer=css`
width: 100%;
height: 60%;
`;

const About =()=>{
    return (
        <div css={content}>
            <p>Who am I ?</p>
            <div css={imageContianer}>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <img
                            src={ Icon }
                            width='200'
                            height='180'
                            alt='Icon' />
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <p>First</p>
                        <p>Second</p>
                        <p>Third</p>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

This is the result. The "Who am i" part even appears in the container above. What's the problem?

[image]

Comment: You want to move "Who am i" in center of container?

Comment: Exactly right. And I want to attach pictures and contents

Comment: I have write an answer for it, hopefully it will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {
    Col, Row,
} from 'react-bootstrap';


const content=css`
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
`;

const imageContianer=css`
width: 100%;
height: 60%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
`;

const rowContainer=css`
flex: 0 0 60% !important;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
`;

const About =()=>{
    return (
        <div css={content}>
            <p>Who am I ?</p>
            <div css={imageContianer}>
                <Row css={rowContainer}>
                    <Col>
                        <img
                            src={ Icon }
                            width='200'
                            height='180'
                            alt='Icon' />
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <p>First</p>
                        <p>Second</p>
                        <p>Third</p>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hopfully code above can solve your problem. basicly you need to know how flex work, it's just like how grid on bootstrap css framwork does.

note: i haven't use styled-components like you do using `css` but i just follow your code example.

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-u343v?file=/src/App.js)

Leave a comment if my answer didn't working out the way want

Comment: Thank you for your time. But it works just like the picture above

Comment: Are you sure `css` things it's affect the component? I just try styling with vanila css not using styled-component

Comment: @sojinLee https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-7zduv?file=/src/App.js you can see in this codesandbox

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: @sojinLee You're welcome, don't forget to mark as correct answer :D